# Adding Scope to OAuth Firebase Auth for Google and Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Facebook gives `user_firends` permission by default. But Firebase Facebook `SigninwithPopProvider` method does not return any key containing the data of `user_friends`.

I have tried adding `provider.addScope('user_friends')` before I make the method call, but it did not return a promise containing the friend data in the nor does it contain complete basic `public_profile` data (*i.e age range*)

For testing I currently have 2 users signed in using Facebook method who are also friends on Facebook and for both, it did not return this data.

Lastly the same question for Google Auth with `provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')`, will that returned promise contain users circle of friends data?

Only thing I receive back from both Oauth Providers is:

```
displayName:
email:
photoURL:
providerId:
uid:
```

My guess is I may have to make a call to Facebook and Google after with access token to request data, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Currently firebase does not return the cached provider data on sign in. You will have to get the facebook access token returned in the the signInWithPopup promise (result.credential.accessToken) and then use that to manually retrieve the facebook scope specific data.

Comment: Which is kind of weird given they did that in version 2.x